# Create a not analyzed field on elasticsearch with c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have an application with an ES repository and I need to add a new field to an already existing index, this field should be not_analyzed. I tried sending a document with the new field and it worked, but the field was added without the 'not_analyze'.

I can't create it manually or recreate the index, because is already on production and each client has his own index.

Is there anyway I can specify that it should be 'not_analyzed' ?

Answer (score 0):

It's too late when you already indexed some data for the field. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#updating-a-mapping)

Variants:

1) Create index with the right mapping and reindex the data (easier to do with recent ES versions that have reindex API) Production is not a problem, you can use alias switching for seamless migration to new index.

2) In the existing index set the right mapping for ***new*** field name, and use this new field name in newer documents.

Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_example_mapping about changing mapping for the index